# Family view and Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I own Skyrim, now suddenly it won't load and tells me the game is not able to be played in family view. I have disabled family view in Steam, restarted but still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem with the Steam configuration files linked to your profile. Your best bet is to **reinstall Steam.**

The games in your library will be detected automatically once you start Steam after the reinstallation process.

Comment: This, but move the appmanifest files from the steamapps folder too so it can avoid the need to "reinstall" (discover existing data).